# What should ABAC PIP do in case of attributes resolution impossibility?

Tags: security, policy, xacml, abac, alfa

How PIP and whole ABAC engine should behave in case if it can't resolve attributes.
There are several cases:

1. Destination object using which we are resolving attribute is not found
2. Attribute can't be resolve because provided attributes not sufficient to request addition information. Like if we passed single userId and resource name without id.
3. If during attributes resolution chain (when some attributes depends from another) something has been missing that make target attribute resolution impossible.

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own?

Comment: @DavidBrossard, Yes I do. There is no any engines nor SDK's for Node.js. We took a small step to start with using the simpliest JSON, parser and some parts from XACML. Currently I've implemented engine with support of rules, policies (without sets), targets filterring and logging. This is enough for the first step. I hope in the future, when we will need more, will try to implement engine for XACML or ALFA specification.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use an existing PDP and simply implement the PEP in NodeJS?

Comment: @DavidBrossard, That's the matter of time. As initial step, the simpliest server implementation that covers 90% of requirements took 3 days to understand the teory and 2 days on implementation. For now this is cheepier, at least until we are starting to work with it. I guess in the future we will review existing solutions. once again, but for now they are really huge and complex, which is cool, but requires efforts to manage them. And also, I was not able to find pure RESTfull or any other kind of dedicated PDP.

Comment: I understand. BTW both Axiomatics and AuthzForce provide REST PDPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interaction between the PDP and the PIP is not specified in the XACML standard. It is down to each implementation (AuthZForce, Axiomatics...) to determine how they handle each case.

Generally speaking, there are 3 errors that can occur when using a PIP:

1. Connection issues: the target PIP (e.g. an LDAP server) cannot be reached
2. Mapping configuration issues: the mapping for the attribute is invalid. For instance you are retrieving an attribute from a non-existing SQL table or column.
3. Data issue: there is no data to be read in the underlying source

In addition, there is another possible issue: the keys used in the mapping (e.g. username) has no value at all. In this case, it is clear that the mapping (e.g. to retrieve a role) will not be invoked at all.

Points 1 and 2 could lead to Indeterminate. This helps the administrator troubleshoot the installation.

Point 3 should lead to NotApplicable for that branch that uses the attribute. If there is no value, then so be it. Why would there necessarily be a value?

I hope this helps,

David.

Answer (score 3):

[ABAC](https://www.nist.gov/publications/guide-attribute-based-access-control-abac-definition-and-considerations) is a broad concept that does not specify this kind of low-level behavior; and it is difficult to give a universal best practice for all ABAC frameworks, since there is a growing bunch of them possibly quite different: some of them are standard (eg. [OASIS XACML](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html), [NIST NGAC](https://www.nist.gov/publications/exploring-next-generation-access-control-methodologies)), others non-standard yet generic (eg. [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/)), others product-specific (eg. [Kubernetes ABAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/)).

It is easier to give tips for the XACML (3.0) standard since the specification is more mature:

1. **§ 5.29** says: *In the event that no matching attribute is present in the context, the **MustBePresent** attribute governs whether this element returns an empty bag or “Indeterminate”.  See Section 7.3.5.* (The MustBePresent is defined on AttributeDesignator elements in your XACML Policy. An AttributeDesignator is a reference to an attribute, for which, in your case, a PIP should be called if the attribute is not available in the current request context.)
2. **§ 7.3.5** gives more details: *If the attribute is missing, then MustBePresent governs whether the attribute designator or attribute selector returns an empty bag or an “Indeterminate” result.  If MustBePresent is “False” (default value), then a missing attribute SHALL result in an empty bag.  If MustBePresent is “True”, then a missing attribute SHALL result in “Indeterminate”.  This “Indeterminate” result SHALL be handled in accordance with the specification of the encompassing expressions, rules, policies and policy sets.  If the result is “Indeterminate”, then the AttributeId, DataType and Issuer of the attribute MAY be listed in the authorization decision as described in Section 7.17.  However, a PDP MAY choose not to return such information for security reasons. [...] Regardless of any dynamic modifications of the request context during policy evaluation, the PDP SHALL behave as if each bag of attribute values is fully populated in the context before it is first tested, and is thereafter immutable during evaluation. (That is, every subsequent test of that attribute shall use the same bag of values that was initially tested.)* **The last sentence means in particular that if PIP attribute resolution results in an empty bag and MustBePresent=False, you should keep the attribute value as empty bag for the rest of the policy evaluation, i.e. NOT try to call the PIP again for the same attribute (risking a value change) in the same context.**
3. **§ 7.19.3** specifies how the PDP should include the information about a missing attribute in its response.
4. Beware that the final result is also affected by combining algorithms in XACML. E.g. even if an AttributeDesignator returns Indeterminate because of a PIP error in a child Rule/Policy(Set), algorithms of the enclosing policy like deny-unless-permit (resp. permit-unless-deny) may return Deny (resp. Permit) regardless.

That's what the standard says, then, there is implementation-specific behavior. In [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/core) XACML implementation for instance, we distinguish the following cases while trying to be as XACML compliant as possible:

1. If PIP internal error occurs during attribute resolution (connection issues, misconfiguration, missing dependency, etc.), then the AttributeDesignator evaluates to Indeterminate regardless of MustBePresent, because we consider this critical, and we add the info *Missing attribute XXX*; we also add info about the cause, e.g. *Missing dependency: attribute YYY* if PIP requires some attribute that was missing from the context to do its job (e.g. *missing dependency: attribute 'subject-id'* if the PIP fetches the user's roles but requires the subject-id attribute to do that, which is missing).
2. If PIP attribute resolution is done error-free but no value found, in other terms the result is empty (e.g. some PIP fetches the user's roles successfuly from a database but gets an empty list because no role has been assigned to the user.), then the AttributeDesignator evaluates to an empty bag if MustBePresent=false, else (if MustBePresent=true) returns Indeterminate with the info *Missing attribute XXX*.